# Oracle PL/SQL, How to calculate age from date birth using simple substitution variable and months_between

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on a simple PL/SQL block that asks the user their Date Of Birth and calculates their age.  I've used the months_between divided by 12 conversion but I am having trouble with the date conversion and date input from the user for the substitution variable. Please ignore the v_birthday_year as that is another part of the code I have to integrate in later.

I'm not sure the format that the user has to type in, ie 05-07-1980, or 06 Mar 1978 that would be acceptable, and how to calculate their age from what they put in.

**My desired program is to write a PL/SQL program to accept the user's birthdate in this format DD-MON-YYYY, and calculates the Age in with 1 Decimal place.  So I need it calculated out to one decimal place too.**

Here is what I have, but I'm not sure what format to type in the DOB at the substitution variable input and the actual calculation with one decimal place.  I'm just trying to see where I'm going wrong and how to correct it.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  --v_birthday_year         NUMBER(4)    := &v_birthday_year;
  v_dob                   DATE      := &v_dob 
  v_your_age              NUMBER(3, 1);
BEGIN
  v_your_age := TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, v_dob))/12;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Your age is ' || v_your_age);
END;
/
```

Comment: A year is made out of 12 months while a decimal place calculate it in base 10 - why would you want to do something like that ? It makes more sense to display the age using years & months or only display the  years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All SQL examples from others and me are probably better thing to use unless you are learning something about PL/SQL. Here's what I came up with:

```
 DECLARE
  v_dob        DATE:= to_date('&v_dob', 'MM/DD/YYYY'); -- copy this line and you'll be fine
  v_your_age   NUMBER(3, 1);
BEGIN
  v_your_age := TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, v_dob))/12;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Your age is ' || v_your_age);
END;
/

I passed 01/01/2010. Got this in output: 

 Your age is 3.1
```

Another SQL example:

```
SELECT empno, ename, hiredate
    , TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hiredate)/12) years_of_service  
 FROM scott.emp
/
```

Comment: Awesome the to_date worked just great!  Oh since I'm calculating to one decimal the trunc was changed trunc(x, 1).

Comment: @MeachamRob - Thank you. And quotes around &v_dob are optional. I like put quotes in advance, so to speak, so I do not have to worry about them later. There are diff. date formats also, or you can use default format w/out format mask as in my example. Default format:  07-FEB-2013

Comment: AskTOM (Connor McDonald) apparently shows that can be wrong in few cases:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9531934000346471628

Recommends :
trunc((to_number(to_char(now,'YYYYMMDD'))- to_number(to_char(birth,'YYYYMMDD')))/10000)

Answer (score 23):

You may use any of these (pure sql)

```
SELECT months_between(sysdate, user_birth_date) /12 FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT floor(months_between(sysdate, user_birth_date) /12) FROM  dual;
```

or

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM user_birth_date) FROM dual
```

or

```
SELECT (sysdate - user_birth_date) / 365.242199 FROM dual
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for the SQL refresher calculations.  They were helpful.

Comment: Its way better to use SQL Queries than go for PLSQL, if the work can be done using a simple query. Nice Answers @Mohsen

Answer (score 0):

```
 Create or replace function getAge(birthday date) return number is
  v_your_age   NUMBER(3, 1);``
  BEGIN
  v_your_age := floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, birthday))/12;  
  return v_your_age;
  END;
   /
```

then you call the function

```
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Your age is ' || getAge(to_date('10/10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')));
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select dob,sysdate,trunc(months_between(sysdate,dob)/12) as year,
   trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate,dob),12)) as month,
   trunc(sysdate - add_months(dob,((trunc(months_between(sysdate,dob)/12)*12) + trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate,dob),12))))) as day
   from emp;
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may resolve the issue, some explanation of your code as to what your doing and why it solves the problem would improve the quality of the answer.  It also is for future reference when people come back to this solution and see why something has been done.

Comment: this sql will give the correct age in year,month and date format without using any plsql block